# ng-repeat not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Hello guys so i was running this simple HTML,Angular code and i can not get the movies title and url display in my html....but the $scope.test is displayinmg....HELP!!

```js
angular.module('clientApp')
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.test = "tester";
    $scope.movies = [
      {
        title:"Green Card",
        url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      },
      {
        title: "Fidelawit ፊደላዊት",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4u4A7CF3N0"
      },
      {
        title: "Heran ሔራን",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TlRGhOdLJ0"
      },
      {
        title: "Lela Mafia ሌላ ማፊያ",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>URL</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Strange because it works on this fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0dekzcek/

Answer (score 1):

Add the `AngularJS` and if it is the first place where you have worked with module, you need define it with empty brackets `angular.module('clientApp', [])`

```js
angular.module('clientApp', [])
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = "tester";
    $scope.movies = [
      {
        title:"Green Card",
        url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      },
      {
        title: "Fidelawit ፊደላዊት",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4u4A7CF3N0"
      },
      {
        title: "Heran ሔራን",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TlRGhOdLJ0"
      },
      {
        title: "Lela Mafia ሌላ ማፊያ",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='clientApp' ng-controller='MoviesCtrl'>
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>URL</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, movie) in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to load angular.js. 
So just add this file on above of all the script files.

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
```

You can download this file from here.. `https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js`

And update `angular.module('clientApp')` to `angular.module('clientApp', [])`

Hence the modified code will look like this...

Controller file (.js)

```
angular.module('clientApp', [])
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
  $scope.test = "tester";
    $scope.movies = [
      {
        title:"Green Card",
        url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      },
      {
        title: "Fidelawit ፊደላዊት",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4u4A7CF3N0"
      },
      {
        title: "Heran ሔራን",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TlRGhOdLJ0"
      },
      {
        title: "Lela Mafia ሌላ ማፊያ",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      }
    ];
  });
```

Html file

```
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='clientApp' ng-controller='MoviesCtrl'>
  <table class="table table-striped">
  <thead>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>URL</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="(key, movie) in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> The problem does not seems too big. Only two things I have done
>
> 1. Added to body to initialise the angular app. B

```
<body ng-app='clientApp'>
```

> 2. Added ng-controller to table tag

```
<table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
```

> However this is must. Must make an [] for zero dependencies.

```
angular.module('clientApp', [])
```

Here it goes

```js
angular.module('clientApp', [])
  .controller('MoviesCtrl', function ($scope) {
$scope.test = "tester";
    $scope.movies = [
      {
        title:"Green Card",
        url:"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      },
      {
        title: "Fidelawit ፊደላዊት",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B4u4A7CF3N0"
      },
      {
        title: "Heran ሔራን",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_TlRGhOdLJ0"
      },
      {
        title: "Lela Mafia ሌላ ማፊያ",
        url: "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_i8C9gO91ts"
      }
    ];
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app='clientApp'>

<table class="table table-striped" ng-controller="MoviesCtrl">
  <thead>
  <th>Title</th>
  <th>URL</th>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="movie in movies">
        <td>{{ movie.title }}</td>
        <td>{{ movie.url }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```